# Sidenav UserView Materialize doesn't work

Tags: materialize

I copied the sample sidenav from of materialize from http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html

So I copied the codes from inspect element and this is what I got

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GROUPIE</title>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
            $('.parallax').parallax();
            $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
            $(".dropdown-button").dropdown({
                hover: false
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav" style="transform: translateX(0px)"> 
        <li>
            <div class="userView">
                <div class="backgroud">
                    <img src="assets/images/asdas.jpg">
                </div>
                <a href="#!user">
                    <img src="assets/images/logo.jpg">
                </a>
                <a href="#!name">
                    <span class="white-text name">
                        Jayvee Javier
                    </span>
                </a>
                <a href="#!email">
                    <span class="white-text email">
                        jayveejavier666@yahoo.com
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>       
</body>
</html>
```

But instead I got a different output which is this (I compared the output from the website and from I actually got)

[Expected Result vs Actualt Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNsbI.png)

The left picture is what it is supposed to look like. The right picture is my actual result.

It is very different from what is shown in the sample. Is there something that I got wrong? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Ahahahh. Hey, I use VS Code [Spelling Checker](https://github.com/streetsidesoftware/vscode-spell-checker) exactly for those cases.
It should be available in any code editor. I have noticed a significant decrease in Typo Errors since I started using it and my spelling got better.)))

Comment: The question being asked has nothing to do with spell-checking.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `class=backgroud` to `class=background`. Works like a charm.